# Windows Phone 7 Web Browser Updating Too Slowly

Tags: javascript, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight with XNA application. 
I'm also using a service which uses javascript to render dynamic images to the screen.

On the PC, the javascript is fluid and smooth, I can jump between images and their transitions smoothly. However, I need to bring this functionality to the phone.

As of right now, I've managed to use the Web Browser control in Silverlight to load my HTML file and execute the script. The problem is that once the "dynamic" part of the application kicks in, the web control doesn't update fast enough. Instead of smooth sliding animations that the PC version results in, I get stutter, similar to having a low FPS in a game.

So, I'm wondering: is there any way to increase the update rate of a web browser control?

Another thought that I've had (but have been unsuccessful at implementing) is to embed a web browser in the XNA page of the application and use XNA's update rate, which is significantly higher (I'm guessing is the standard 60 fps). However, the Silverlight web broweser control doesn't seem to have an update rendering function and the I can't find a library to embed a web browser inside the XNA application itself.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get my dynamic HTML file with javascript to render fluidly and smoothly?

**EDIT:**
webBrowser.InvalidateArrange() using a Timer at 30 FPS seems to have sped up the browser refresh but it's still jumpy. If I try to increase the FPS, the browser reverts back to being slow.

Comment: This may just be an issue of the hardware and JS engine on the phone being slow. You could try doing your animations with CSS transforms - that helps a lot on most mobile devices.

Comment: Since I'm using a third party javascript library (which provides a control for me), I can't use anything other than JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Timer set at 17 milliseconds (60 FPS) I force the invalidation of the browser, which causes it to redraw. In addition to this, I eliminated frames where the browser did not need to be redrawn.

```
    DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 17); // 30 FPS 
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Start();

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (loaded && coded && needToUpdate)
        {
                webBrowser.InvokeScript("setPitch", pitch.ToString());
                webBrowser.InvokeScript("setHeading", heading.ToString());
                Redraw();

                needToUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    void Redraw()
    {
        webBrowser.InvalidateMeasure();
        webBrowser.InvalidateArrange();
        webBrowser.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm guessing is the standard 60 fps

standard is 30 FPS

> I can't find a library to embed a web browser inside the XNA application itself.

I don't think it will get any improvements.

> So, I'm wondering: is there any way to increase the update rate of a
>   web browser control?

1. Make a test app that has only a web browser control on the main page - make sure that there is nothing that eats the resources except the web control.
2. Check how the app performs. If it's good enough reduce any other processing in your app while user uses the "dynamic" part
3. If the performance is still poor, only thing you can do is to optimize javascript itself
4. If it's still unacceptable cut the feature or make a native one.
5. Profit!

Comment: Currently the browser app is the only thing on the main page. There is no other processing when the browser is up. I can't optimize the javascript since it's a third party library and I don't have the access to it (it's by Google, so I would imagine it's already pretty optimized). I can't cut the feature because this is the feature. I can't make a native one, don't have the resources/can't violate Google TOS. Re XNA performance: XNA games update pretty fast. I would imagine a web browser built for XNA would function well. I just haven't found one yet.

Comment: Google is prolly targeting a wide range of browsers and is not very likely that they optimized it for WP7. Web Control is native it doesn't matter where it is hosted. If you cannot redesign/cut/optimize you're doomed.